# How do I programmatically put a text value into a NSTextField in OSX?

Tags: macos, xcode6, nstextfield

I am able to type a value into the text field and add the value to an array I created. Therefore I know the delegate is set correctly.

When I try to set the text field with the value from the array it will not set and the field is empty.

I am setting the text field like this:

```
setStringValue:inputDecsription  = [descriptionArrayobjectAtIndex:selected];

NSLog(@"Description %@", inputDecsription);
Description Florida Power
```

The text field remains empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's obviously not your code. Post your code. Especially since something is wrong with your code. And _I_ won't post a fix that involves a variable named inputDecsription.